# How to build a golang file if it has dependency with Asset function

Tags: go, compiler-errors

I have the below Golang file:

```
**main.go**

func indexPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var (
        data []byte
        err  error
    )
    if ExtAssetDir == "" {
        data, err = Asset("index.html")
    } else {
        var f *os.File
        f, err = os.Open(ExtAssetDir + "/index.html")
        data, err = ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    }
```

Which has the dependency to Asset package/function. How can I include that(Asset) dependency when building main.go. When I build **main.go** I get the following error

> .\main.go:30:15: undefined: Asset
>
> .\main.go:35:13: undefined: AssetInfo

Comment: [Please take the Go tour.](https://tour.golang.org/basics/2)

Comment: Also see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) and [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), all part of the standard documentation.

Comment: That looks like [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata). It's a code generator. You'll have to download that tool and run it. I'm assuming your project has a `go generate` script, `Makefile`, or something to run the command. What other files do you have in the root of your project? It should generate a file that has those functions in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata). It's a code generator. You'll have to download that tool and run it.

Your project probably has a `go generate` script, Makefile, or bash script to run the command. Otherwise, read the README for go-bindata to see how to generate your file correctly. It's supposed to create a go file that has your static files encoded into it.

Once you run it, it will generate your `Asset` function in a new file so you can compile.